# iconv translate english to russian language

Tags: locale

I am trying to find a command in Unix to translate English characters to Russian. So I first listed the Russian locales available in my box:

```
#locale -a | grep -i RU
ru_RU
ru_RU.iso88595
ru_RU.koi8r
ru_RU.utf8
russian
```

Now I am trying a command to convert English chars to Russian characters or rather translate equivalently:

```
#iconv -f en_US.utf8 "Hi" -t ru_RU.utf8
iconv: conversions from `en_US.utf8' and to `ru_RU.utf8' are not supported
```

I tried various google pages and other command but not able to find exact command for my purpose?

Please suggest which command would produce the expected result.

Comment: You are not showing what the expected result should be or what you're trying to convert.  Do you realize that your command, if it were supported, wouldn't change anything in the data?

Comment: Please do not use multiple accounts.  Come back with the original account to do your modifications.

Comment: `iconv` is a character encoding converter, not a language translator.

Comment: `echo "Hi" | iconv -f utf-8 -t koi8-ru` is still "Hi", all russian character sets support latin letters

Comment: Plainly said, you're asking the wrong question.  You should post another question to get help finding a translation program.

Answer (score 2):

The message

```
iconv: conversions from `en_US.utf8' and to `ru_RU.utf8' are not supported
```

could be improved, e.g.,

```
iconv: conversions from `en_US.utf8' and to `ru_RU.utf8' is pointless
```

or

```
iconv: conversions from `en_US.utf8' and to `ru_RU.utf8' will not modify your data
```

`iconv` translates character *encoding*.  While it may recognize the name of a *locale*, there is a difference between *encoding* and *locale*:

- **encoding** lists all of the available character *codes* in a character set, with reference to the *appearance* of the characters (referred to as *glyphs*).
- **locale** tells how the characters in a *given encoding* are used, e.g., which are printable, which are not, which are used for special cases such as decimal separators.  It also deals with things that are not related to character sets, such as the names for the days of the week.

Since both locales `en_US.utf8` and `ru_RS.utf8` use the *same* encoding, `iconv` has nothing to do.  Since it cannot guess what you might be trying to do, it tells you that the conversion is "not supported".

What `iconv` *does support* is conversions between *different* encodings.  For instance, in your list

```
ru_RU.iso88595
ru_RU.koi8r
```

do not use UTF-8 encoding.   Those are used for character sets with fewer than 256 characters; UTF-8 is used for Unicode, with ***many*** more than 256 characters.

As for what is the correct command to use, that depends on what the actual encoding of your input file is (it might be UTF-8, it might be ISO-8859-1), and whether you want the output to be UTF-8 (no problem) or one of the other encodings (less likely, and involving some loss of information).